# play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NumberFormatException: null] on HTTP GET request to endpoint

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an Play 2.4.2 REST application which exposes the /api/availability-stream-metrics endpoint.

The routes file is as below:

GET           /api/availability-stream-metrics                                               @controllers.MetricsController.availabilityStreamMetrics()

Sometimes a HTTP GET on /api/availability-stream-metrics results in the play.api.UnexpectedException given below. Subsequent requests to /api/availability-stream-metrics do not get any response.

MetricsController.availabilityStreamMetrics() returns a JSON response.

The endpoint is queried every 60 seconds but even so this error occurs very rarely, a few times a month. There is no discernible pattern to its occurrence.

Scala version: 2.11.8

Is this a known issue with play/akka?

```
! @7267i94mm - Internal server error, for (GET) [/api/availability-stream-metrics] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NumberFormatException: null]
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]
akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]
scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.8.jar:na]
```

Comment: My guess would be this exception is occurring at marshalling level. You occasionally might have a `null` number coming from your metrics logic, and the JSON library (play-json?) doesn't like it.

Comment: I am not sure, it could be like that I suppose. This has only occurred twice in the last few months. When it happens, the endpoint just dies and does not respond to requests anymore. Its probably because the underlying akka actor died and is not restarted automatically. I should probably look at how that can be done.